# How to bring MDI child form to front of picture box in c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem, I have a main form and I put a picturebox on it. Then I create a child form, I want to bring it to front of picturebox.

Like History box in this picture
[image]

can anyone help me!!

p/s: English is not my native English so can have some errors

Comment: The History window in your image is not an MDI child. It's a top level window, whose owner is the Paint.NET main window.

Answer (score 0):

mdiChildForm.[BringToFront()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try use mdiChildForm.Activate();

which is equivilant to:

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.Focus();
this.BringToFront();
this.TopMost = false;
```

How to use: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx)

Source: [Here](http://blog.jorgearimany.com/2010/10/win32-setforegroundwindow-equivalent-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a MDI application...

At any rate, the "History" box in that image is a "**Tool Window**".  Set its `FormBorderStyle()` property to "FixedToolWindow", its `ShowInTaskBar()` property to false, and set its `Opacity()` property to 70 or 80.

Then display it by passing in the "owner" like this:

```
    private void MainMdiForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        History hist = new History();
        hist.Show(this);
    }
```